# Book Introduction to Climate Change

Tags: climate-change

The question might be in an opinion-based grey zone. If it is, I apologize.

My wife and I want to get informed about climate change.
We want to read a book (no online course etc.) and it should be either in English or available in Portuguese and German. It is supposed to "start from the beginning" e.g. treating us as people that almost don't know anything about it.
We wish a rather scientific approach (for example with references to papers) and it should of course talk about the strongest evidences of the existence of the climate problem and its causes.

After some short internet research we thought of "[The Rough Guide to Climate Change of Robert Henson](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10541833-the-rough-guide-to-climate-change).

The question is: Would this be a good choice?
Does it fulfill our requirements? And since it is (at least) 9 years old, is it maybe too old?
Maybe some significant findings were added in this time.
And if it isn't a good choice can you recommend other books?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give it more focus. Should it yes/no be about physics/biology/earth science/economy/politics/psychology etc...

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend *Climate: A Very Short Introduction* and *Climate Change: A Very Short Introduction*, both by Mark Maslin and published through Oxford U Press's highly-regarded VSI series. I use both books when teaching college-level classes where an understanding of climate and climate change are important to the subject matter but are not the sole focus of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a free (at least until tomorrow) download:
[Climate Change Science: A Modern Synthesis

Volume 1 - The Physical Climate

G. Thomas FarmerJohn Cook](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-94-007-5757-8)

Answer (score 0):

Since German books are ok with you, I definitely can recommend

"Klimawandel und Klimadynamik"

by Mojib Latif.

It costs about 10 € and covers all the basics on climate change and dynamics, though it is 11 years old. Still, the author is one of the leading scientists on climate in Germany and teaches excellent courses for Bachelor students.